# Keyboard controls for Select/Combobox

Tags: html, reactjs, select, combobox, wai-aria

I want to create a Select (ComboBox) with functionality for users with disabilities and I got this idea:

Can aria-tags change control of an element if I use the keyboard?
For example, if I press "arrow up" or "arrow down" on the keyboard in the dropdown list?

If its possible I will be grateful for a simple example. This will shorten my code and make it cleaner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a right solution.

There are ARIA-patterns. And this pattern is called 'Combobox'.

More information and examples:
https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/combobox/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also add the details you found in the URL you provided. (Thinking, the URL might be broken on some day and your answer will not be valid at that time).